# SQL AVG function:

Tags: sql, sqlplus

What does AVG do with columns with NULL values if we compute AVG over that column? Does it compute the average by considering NULL as zeroes or it computes average by excluding null values?
I can do it by creating a demo table, but I'm in hurry and need some quick answers. Whole assignment is revolving around this point.

Comment: null is never assumed to be a 0 by the database.

Comment: null is considered null, that's why it's null

Comment: In every implementation of databases? I mean Oracle 9i?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See here: "Null values are ignored" http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177677.aspx

If you want to make sure you are not averaging `NULL` and do not want to research, you could always add on `WHERE myColumn IS NOT NULL`

Comment: I am using Oracle, may be 9i, can you answer specific to Oracle 9i'

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.2.2/ref/rrefsqlj32693.html

Comment: Thanks david, brain becomes numb when you're in hurry.! Thanks again!